# Send to back-end two-dimensional array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I want to send two-dimensional array to controller from a script using ajax:

This is the code of my script:

```
var regions = [["en", "fr"], ["ru"]];
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     traditional: true,
     url: $(this).attr("action"),
     data: {
         regions: regions
     },
     success: function(data) {
         $('#alertMessage').html(data);
     }
});
```

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveSettings(List<List<string>> regions)
{}
```

The parameter "regions" contains a Null value.

I would appreciate any method that will give the data in the controller (welcome any format: array, json)

I hope for your help.

Best Regards,
Pavel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your action method's signature to use a `string[][]`, like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveSettings(string[][] regions)
{

}
```

Then in your script you can `stringify()` your JSON, like this:

```
var regions = [["en", "fr"], ["ru"]];
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     traditional: true,
     contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
     url: $(this).attr("action"),
     data: {
         JSON.stringify({ regions: regions })
     },
     success: function(data) {
         $('#alertMessage').html(data);
     }
});
```

Note: This requires the inclusion of [JSON.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Comment: Chances are you should add `contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"` to your `$.ajax` options.

Comment: @PavelIvanov - great, glad it helped. Feel free to up-vote the answer, when you can. :-)